# Spring Integration Webservices

Tags: spring-integration

I am very new at spring integration, I am trying to convert following code into spring integration code but I am not able to send the request properly.
I really don't know what I am doing wrong and what to do, actually the task is to split the XML which are sending to webservices then get the response back from it and then aggregate to make it one XML.
Normal code:

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection) validateServer.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                String parameters = "";
                if (isMultipleVal) {
                    parameters = ADD_FUNCTION2
                            + URLEncoder.encode(getxmldatalist, "UTF-8");
                } else {
                    parameters = ADD_FUNCTION
                            + URLEncoder.encode(getxmldatalist, "UTF-8");
                }
                LOG.info("parameters:" + parameters);
                System.out.println("In client parameters "+parameters);
                byte[] parameterAsBytes = parameters.getBytes();

                System.out.println("Parameters as bytes "+parameterAsBytes);
                connection.setRequestProperty(CONTENT_LENGTH,String.valueOf(parameterAsBytes.length));

                OutputStream oStream = connection.getOutputStream();
                oStream.write(parameterAsBytes, 0, parameterAsBytes.length);
                oStream.flush();
                oStream.close();
```

Spring Integration code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-xml="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml" 
    xmlns:int-ws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws" 
    xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int-stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml/spring-integration-xml.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws/spring-integration-ws.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd">

<int:channel id="requestGatewayChannel"/>

<int:gateway id="serviceGateway" service-interface="xxx.xxx.xxx"    default-request-channel="requestGatewayChannel" default-reply-channel="replyGatewayChannel" />

<int:channel id="replyGatewayChannel"/>

<int:splitter ref="rootSplitter" input-channel="requestGatewayChannel" output-channel="splitterOutputChannel" method="splitRoot"/>

<int:channel id="splitterOutputChannel"/>

<bean id="rootSplitter" class="xxx.xxx.xxx.VehicleRootSpliter" />

<int-xml:marshalling-transformer id="marshaller" input-channel="splitterOutputChannel" output-channel="marshallerOutputChannel" marshaller="marshallerUnmarshaller" result-type="StringResult" />

<int:channel id="marshallerOutputChannel"></int:channel>

<int:object-to-string-transformer input-channel="marshallerOutputChannel" output-channel="stringOutputChannel"></int:object-to-string-transformer>

<int:channel id="stringOutputChannel"></int:channel>

<int:transformer id="dataTransformer" input-channel="stringOutputChannel" output-channel="dataTransformerOutputChannel" ref="xmlToEncode" method="dataTransformer"></int:transformer>
---To encode the string of xml using custom transformer---
<int:channel id="dataTransformerOutputChannel"></int:channel>

<bean id="xmlToEncode" class="xxx.xxx.xxx.DataTransformer"></bean>

<int:header-enricher default-overwrite="true" input-channel="dataTransformerOutputChannel" output-channel="enricherOutputChannel">

    <int:header name="Content_length" ref="headerBean" method="valueLength"></int:header>

</int:header-enricher>

<int:channel id="enricherOutputChannel"></int:channel>

<bean id="headerBean" class="xxx.xxx.xxx.DataTransformer"></bean>

<int-http:outbound-gateway url="${toms.ws.url}" request-channel="enricherOutputChannel" reply-channel="httpOutputChannel" 
    header-mapper="headerMapper" http-method="POST" 
    expected-response-type="java.lang.String"/>
<bean id="headerMapper" class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper">
    <property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, Content_length"></property>
    <property name="userDefinedHeaderPrefix" value=""></property>
</bean>

<int:channel id="httpOutputchannel"></int:channel>

<int:service-activator input-channel="httpOutputChannel" ref="webserviceActivator" method="checkerWeb"></int:service-activator>

<bean id="webserviceActivator" class="xxx.xxx.xxx"></bean>

<bean id="marshallerUnmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller" >
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>com.xxx.xxx.xxx.VRoot</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Everything looks good. You have to demonstrate what's going wrong: StackTrace, some logs etc. Sorry, but we can't do the work for you. More over I don't see how your original code split and then aggregate XML before and after HTTP request performing.

Comment: Actually I am not able to trace the problem, I don't how to take log of spring integration

Comment: How ever I will give you the logs and the splitter and aggregator code. But the previous code written using HTTPURLCONNECTION is working fine with that webservices, I think some thing I am missing before sending the XML some header or something else.

Comment: Thanks for the Artem Bilan for your support. I'll give you those code, may be you can help me out on that.

Comment: Spring Integration is a Java anyway. So, its logs are fully similar to any other your logs. You should just configure `org.springframework.integration` category to log. But that doesn't matter. You say you have problem with service invocation. So, how does that problem look? StackTrace into the studio! Everything rest is your job. We can share an idea (you're good here already), or let to know how to use components (you're good again!). All other business details of your code are out of our scope to support. You have to describe the problem: I would like to see this result, but it does that.